# How to parse a String and then divide?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I am new to C# so this might seem like a silly question to some. 
I have an address string such as

> 10 Enjay Dr. Baltimore GA 30319

I want to know how to split it into 4 chunks and display into seperate lables.
One label for street, city, state, and zip-code.
The street address changes by the user so I can not program the form to read the only first 7 digits.

Thank you for your help :)

---

```
string Address = "10 Enjay Dr. Baltimore GA 30319"
String[] tokens = Address.Split(" ");
            String street = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1] + " " + tokens[2];
            MessageBox.Show(street);
            string city = tokens[3];
            MessageBox.Show(city);
            string state = tokens[4];
            MessageBox.Show(state);
            string zipcode = tokens[5];
            MessageBox.Show(zipcode);
```

This is my own solution but like everybody said that space is not good way to split the string. Thank you everybody for your feedback.

Comment: Do you have any pattern to split your string? So your first 7 characters (without space) are street, what about the others?

Comment: How would you parse `1 East Main St New York NY 10210`?

Comment: @D Stanley That is a good question... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people said, you could do it with `.Split()`. However, to deal with multi-space cases for both city and state, it is effectively impossible to do if your separator is spaces as well. In case only one of them is multi-worded (or, well, street names are only number and one word), you can do something of the sort:

```
//Single-word city name
string str = "10 Enjay Dr. Baltimore GA 30319"
string[] ss = str.Split(" ");
string zip = ss[ss.Count - 1];
string state = ss[ss.Count - 2];
string city = ss[ss.Count - 3];
string address = "";
for(int i=0;i<ss.Count - 4;i++)
  address += ss[i];
```

Switching that around you can also do the single-word address / multi-word city name case. That being said, the choice of space as a delimiter in a list of data that contains spaces as valid characters is a terrible idea. Any reason not to use an unusual delimiter such as %? Or, since who cares?, why not something like "$%$"? Good luck finding a case which contains that particular string as valid input.